# Склонение "артиллерист-наводчик"

Tags: грамотная-речь

"В качестве артиллериста-наводчика" - склоняются оба слова?

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае возможны параллельные падежные формы: в разговорной речи склоняется только вторая часть, в книжной – обе части.  Ср.: у капитан-лейтенанта – у инженера-экономиста (в первом случае слитный термин, во втором – сочетание определяемого слова и приложения при нем). В вашем случае **артиллерист-наводчик** - сочетание определяемого слова и приложения при нем: специальность - *артиллерист*, а *наводчик* - специализация.